# How to set the SelectedItem when having databound ListPicker?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit, selecteditem, listpicker

I have a CartPage in WindowsPhone App. It shows Items in cart with their selected quantities.
I use a ListPicker to change the quantity. Now I have two questions,

1. How to set the default Quantity in ListPicker (I am getting the Quantity of product from localstorage).
2. When I select the quantity from ListPicker, How to save it into variable?

   ```
   <Grid.Resources>

       <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="16 21 0 20" >
               <TextBlock Name="TextQuantity" Text="{Binding Quantity}" Margin="16 0 0 0" FontSize="43" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>

           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </Grid.Resources>
   ```

---

```
<toolkit:ListPicker   toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Name="QuantityBox" Margin="264,91,142,36" Background="#FFA05E6A" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}" BorderBrush="#FF8D7373" Foreground="#FF310836" FontSize="20" SelectionChanged="QuantityBox_SelectionChanged" MouseEnter="QuantityBox_MouseEnter" BorderThickness="1"/>
```

---

```
   public class ListQuantityClass
    {
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

    }

   List<ListQuantityClass> QuantitySource = new List<ListQuantityClass>();

                for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
                {
                    QuantitySource.Add(new ListQuantityClass() { Quantity = i });
                }
                Custom.QuantityBox.ItemsSource = QuantitySource;
```

Both the below lines are giving me error:

```
                   Custom.QuantityBox.SelectedItem = cart.ProductQuantity;
                singletonInstance.QuantityChanged = int.Parse(QuantityBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

---

Actually Its obvious QuantityBox.SelectedItem WONT WORk because ListPicker is Databdound to QuantitySource  list.  What to use instead of QuantityBox.SelectedItem?

Comment: Can you please Look at this screenshot, I have marked my ListPicker. observe what it shows: How to get cart.ProductQuantity instead of XML_PARSING in it.
http://s30.postimg.org/odk6tr4g1/Screenshot_24.png

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a two part question I will split it up into two sections.

---

- **How to set the default Quantity in ListPicker (I am getting the
  Quantity of product from localstorage).**

You can set the SelectedItem only to an item in the ItemSource.  Using your example,

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    List<ListQuantityClass> QuantitySource = new List<ListQuantityClass>();

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            QuantitySource.Add(new ListQuantityClass() { Quantity = i });
        }
        my_listpicker.ItemsSource = QuantitySource;

        // setting default value to 3
        my_listpicker.SelectedItem = QuantitySource[2];

        // fancy search and set
        // my_SetSelectedItemBasedOnQuantity(my_listpicker, 4); // this will set it to 4

    }
}
```

---

- **When I select the quantity from ListPicker, How to save it into
  variable?**

This is a much more involved problem.  You can loop through the Items in the ItemSource and check to see if it equals the SelectedItem and saved it that way.  But I much prefer if you use an event, like so.

```
    private void my_listpicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var listpicker = sender as ListPicker;
            if (listpicker != null)
            {
                var selected_item = listpicker.SelectedItem as ListQuantityClass;
                int quantity = selected_item.Quantity;

                // TODO: Save the value in quantity to a file or send it to a webservice
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error_message = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

---

XAML

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" FontSize="43"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" Margin="16 0 0 0" FontSize="43"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>


    <toolkit:ListPicker Header="my list picker demo"  x:Name="my_listpicker" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}" SelectionChanged="my_listpicker_SelectionChanged" MaxHeight="300"/>
```

---

Function to set SelectedItem based on Quantity

```
    private void my_SetSelectedItemBasedOnQuantity(ListPicker lp, int quantity)
    {
        // first search for quantity if a match is found set it
        try
        {

            foreach (ListQuantityClass lqc in lp.ItemsSource)
            {
                // match found
                if (lqc.Quantity == quantity)
                {
                    lp.SelectedItem = lqc;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Regarding your         my_listpicker.SelectedItem = QuantitySource[2];
, i tried using:                    Custom.QuantityBox.SelectedItem = QuantitySource[cart.ProductQuantity];
but still the default item is "XMLParsing.Cart+ListQuantityClass"

Comment: Oh you forgot to use define an ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}", I will update the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It shows my FIRST Item now while opening page. i have two questions now: 1: How to get This Default Item from Cart.ProductQuantity? 2: My Listpicker is opening in FULLMODE. How to open it like a combobox and not fullscreen?

Comment: I am using    `<DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuantityUser}" FontSize="20"/>
            </DataTemplate>` and 
                   `List<UserQuantityClass> QuantityUserList = new List<UserQuantityClass>();
                   QuantityUserList.Add(new UserQuantityClass() { QuantityUser = cart.ProductQuantity });` But it giving me blank. No selected item is now.

Comment: Non "FULLMODE" is achieved by giving it a MaxHeight.  Updated the solution.  As for the other question, you want to write a search function to search for the item in the itemsource that matches your selection.  Then set it to that.

Comment: I will write a search and setting function for you in a bit.  Solution Updated.

Comment: I tried using  MaxHeight="300" but, it still opening FULLSCREEN mode

Comment: Also, tell me where to call my_SetSelectedItemBasedOnQuantity?

Comment: I implemented everything, no error, debugged Line By Line, everything working as expcted but Still not showing the quantity on Listpicker

Comment: After using this method,  even commented `<!--<DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuantityUser}" FontSize="20"/>
            </DataTemplate>-->`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58486/discussion-between-chubosaurus-software-and-atif-shabeer).

Comment: I think after using this method, we need to change Binding QuantityUser in this code: `     <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuantityUser}" FontSize="20"/>
            </DataTemplate>` What to replace here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use `SelectedItem` to set the selected item.You should set the `SelectedIndex` property instead. `SelectedItem` is used to get the selected item.Although the docs say that it can be used to set the selected item,I have never seen any practical implementation of the same.

Comment: Can you please Look at this screenshot, I have marked my ListPicker. observe what it shows: How to get cart.ProductQuantity instead of XML_PARSING in it.
http://s30.postimg.org/odk6tr4g1/Screenshot_24.png

Comment: Please show how you are setting cart.ProductQuantity

Comment: cart.ProductQuantity is coming from database, and its working well. I tested it in individual textbox.

Comment: I tried:
Custom.QuantityBox.SelectedItem = new ListQuantityClass() { Quantity = cart.ProductQuantity };
But Still Default Item in ListPicker is not coming.

Comment: @AtìfShabëër: So what you are saying is that cart is the object of type ListQuantityClass? Still your's is not the correct way of doing things.

Comment: Though everything works fine but The quantity listpicker gives me "XMLParsing.Cart+ListQuantityClass" as it default Item. Where XMLParsing is name of namespace, Cart is name of class and ListQuantityClass is class made for defining the List.

Comment: Chekout this link: You will observe that default Item is XMLParsing.Cart+ListQuantityClass, so my question is how to set this default item when page loads to something like 5,10...etc

Comment: Try this: <TextBlock Name="TextQuantity" Text="{Binding Path=Quantity}" Margin="16 0 0 0" FontSize="43" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>

Comment: Even I tried:
                   Custom.QuantityBox.SelectedItem = Custom.QuantityBox.SelectedIndex.Equals(cart.ProductQuantity);

But giving me an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.DLL but was not handled in user code

Comment: When user opens the Page, the quantity he has choosed previously must be the default SelectedItem in this ListPicker

Comment: Now changed it to:                    Custom.QuantityBox.SelectedItem.Equals(Custom.QuantityBox.SelectedIndex.Equals(cart.ProductQuantity));
But still default item in ListPicker is  XMLParsing.Cart+ListQuantityClass